# Best parallel method for calculating the integral of a 2D function

Tags: algorithm, integration, parallel-processing, numerical-methods

In some crunching number program, I have a function which can be just 1 or 0 in three dimensions. I do not know in advance the function, but I need to know the total "surface" of the function which is equal to zero. In a similar problem I could draw a rectangle over the 2D representation of the map of United Kingdom. The function is equal to 0 at sea, and 1 at the earth. I need to know the total water surface. I wonder what is the best parallel algorithm or method for doing this.

I thought first about the following approach; a) divide 2D map area into a rectangular grid. For each point that belongs to the center of each cell, check whether it is earth of water. This can be done in parallel. At the end of the procedure I will have a matrix with ones and zeroes. I will get the area with some precision. Now I want to increase this precision, so b) choose the cells that are in the border regions between zeroes and ones (what is the best criterion for doing this?) and in those cells, divide them again into successive cells and repeat the process until one gets the desired accuracy. I guess that in this process, the critical parameters are the grid size for each new stage, and how to store and check the cells that belong to the border area. Finally the most optimal method, from the computational point of view, is the one that performs the minimal number of checks in order to get the value of the total surface with the desired accuracy.

Comment: Do you have some rules about the map? For example if you have homogeneous areas you don't have to check the pixels in the given area. If you have some rules you can exclude parts of the map from checking using a formula, which mathematically describes the area surface and you can use approximations for parts of the map where none of your rules apply.

Comment: I understand what you mean but I do not have that rules (which could be applicable to a real england map, for instance)

Comment: OK, this means you need an approximation. I think both answers are reasonable. Just remember, the more precision you want the more operations are needed and the bigger the speed you want the less precision you get. There is no "magical" solution which is precise and quick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that your attitude is reasonable.

**Choose the cells that area in the border regions between zeroes and ones (what is the best criterion for doing this?)**

Each cell has 8 sorrunding cells (3x3), or 24 sorrunding cells (5x5). If at least one of the 9 or 25 cells contains land, and at least one of these cells contains water - increase the accuracy for the whole block of cells (3x3 or 5x5) and query again.

When the accuracy is good enough - instead of splitting, just add the land area to the sum.

**Efficiency**

Use a producers-consumer queue. Create *n* threads, where *n* equals to the number of cores on your machine. All threads should do the same job:

- Dequeue a geo-cell from the queue
- If the area of the cell is still large - divide it into 3x3 or 5x5 cells, for each of the split cells check for land/sea. If there is a mix - enqueue all these cells. If it only land: just add the area. only sea: do nothing.

For start, just divide the whole area into reasonable sized cell and equeue all of them.

You can also optimize by not adding all the 9 or 25 cells when there is a mix, but examine the pattern (only top/bottom/left/right cells).

**Edit:**

There is a tradeoff between accuracy and performance: If the initial cell size is too large, you may miss small lakes or small islands. therefore the optimization criteria should be: start with the largest cells possible that will assure enough accuracy.

Comment: yes, I agree with you, but my worries are that how can I do it with the minimal number of calculations; i.e., which optimal numbers are for total initial number of cells, and consecutive division and why

Comment: @Lior: perhaps the OP's question is how to calculate the number of grid cells required based on accuracy. For example, given the accuracy 0.05 what is the number of cells (or Monte Carlo random points)?

Comment: Using the deterministic method I suggested, anything that has a dimensional side smaller than the grid resolution may be missed. I'm not suggesting random sampling, so it is quite trivial.

Comment: ok, you gave the best answer, but there are still better options to explore

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it looks like you are talking about **3D** function, e.g. for two coordinates x and y you have `f(x, y) = 0` if (x, y) belongs to the sea, and `f(x, y) = 1` otherwise.

Having said that, you can use the following simple approach.

1. Split your rectangle into N subrectangles, where N is the number of
   your processors (or processor cores, or nodes in a cluster, etc.)
2. For each subrectangle use [Monte Carlo method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method) to calculate the
   surface of the water.
3. Add the N values to calculate the total surface of the water.

Of course, you can use any other method to calculate the surface, Mothe Carlo was just an example. But the idea is the same: subdivide your problem to N subproblems, solve them in parallel, then combine the results.

**Update:** For the Monte Carlo method the error estimate decreases as 1/sqrt(N) where N is the number of samples. For instance, to reduce the error by a factor of 2 requires a 4-fold increase in the number of sample points.

Comment: thanks. yes, I agree with you, but the point is how to have a method which is very efficient, from the computational point of view, so I do the less possible divisions, etc. And in your answer there are no details about speed or accuracy, but I will have a look at

Comment: It is difficult to talk about speed at this stage as I don't know anything about your map in the first place. But it's obvious that if your map is a bitmap with size M x N, then in order to be 100% accurate you have to inspect every single point of the map, which gives us O(M*N) complexity. To minimize it you can use approximations, of course.

Comment: I think that the MC method is not the best for accuracy increase

Comment: Of course not, but it's very easy to implement and measure its performance on your **real** data. It may appear that you don't need an extra optimization.

Comment: I know MC method and really need high performance for my algorithm, that is why I am asking here

Comment: The problem is that you don't know the function in advance, but want to calculate the accuracy in advance. How can you do that? If you only have data points (the 1's and 0's in your map), you don't have any reference to measure the accuracy of an any approximate method. Am I overlooking something?

Comment: yes, you are right about that. I do not want to tell all the whole problem in detail but there are some known analytical cases where I know in advance the shape of the land and I can compare with it